# Unable to open SharePoint site in SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-standard

I'm unable to open a SharePoint site in SharePoint Designer and getting below error:

[image]

Even after clicking on OK several times, the same popups appears each time and all I could do is close the SPD from task manager.

How to proceed further?

Any help is appreciated.

We are using SharePoint 2013 Standard.

**Update**:
I'm getting below error only for the host web and is working fine for the site collection.

Comment: Did you try clearing the cache? Its in "~\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache" and "~\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache". Try clearing everything and then reconnecting.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of troubleshooting methods that you can try.

1. **Allowing anonymous authentication** - 
   Go to the IIS manager. 
   In the sites section you will see "SharePoint web Services".
   Click on the site and in the panel in the middle you will see "Authentication" section. 
   Enable Anonymous authentication from there.
   Complete an IIS reset and site should start loading in the SharePoint designer.
2. **Make changes in Web.config**

   Open IIS on SharePoint server > Expand server > Expand Sites > Select your 
    IIS site > Right click > Explore

   Now Open the web.config file after taking backup of same

   Find the line: `<system.serviceModel>`

   Now you need to add the following Line directly below the line:

   `<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled=”true”/>`

   Now click Start > Run > type IISRESET.

Comment: I don't want to enable anonymous access to the site as this is an intranet project.
I cannot the see line in your answer.

Comment: The line is system.service.model , below that line you can add servicehostingenvironment aspnetcompatibilityenabled="true"/ in tag

Answer (score 1):

Do you know if you have the correct permissions to use Sharepoint Designer? You'll need to make sure you have remote interface permission enabled for your permission level. I would check that first and if that's all set properly set you might try restarting the server before you delve into more invasive troubleshooting methods.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all try clearing designer cache. steps are given below:

1. Close SPD2013.
2. Delete everything at %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache
3. Delete everything at %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache
4. Go to SPD2013 options –> General –> Application Options –> Uncheck the “Cache site data across SharePoint Designer sessions”.

If this doesn't work for you, try following solution.
I found similar questions [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115848/sharepoint-2013-designer-issue-server-could-not-complete-your-request) on stackexchange, [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29091.sharepoint-designer-troubleshooting-the-server-could-not-complete-your-request.aspx) on microsoft technet, and [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/error-the-server-could-not-complete-your-request-when-tryi/) on c-sharpcorner.

Please upvote if this answer helped you in any way.